# ng-container printed outside container

Tags: angular, angular-components, ng-content

I'm building a custom modal component (I wanted something simple) and I found this behaviour that I can't understand.

This is my modal component HTML

```
<div class="modal-overlay">
  <div class="modal-main">
    <ng-content selector="header"></ng-content>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <ng-content selector="footer"></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I use this component template everything works fine, I can use the component later on like this and will work as spected.

```
<app-modal>
  <header><h1>Hello modal!</h1></header>
  <div class="modal-content">This is a modal that will be printed nicely</div>
  <footer><button>Close</button></footer>
</app-modal>
```

The problem comes when I try to encapsulate one of the `ng-content` inside a div.
If I do

```
<div class="modal-overlay">
  <div class="modal-main">
    <div class="is-flex">
      <ng-content selector="header"></ng-content>
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <ng-content selector="footer"></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

The resulting HTML will be the following.

```
<div _ngcontent-c1="" class="modal-overlay">
  <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="modal-main">
    <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="is-flex">
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </div>
    <header><h1>Hello modal!</h1></header>
    <div class="modal-content">This is a modal that will be printed nicely</div> 
    <footer><button>Close</button></footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas why the `header` doesn't end inside the `.is-flex` div?
Thanks!

Comment: What version of angular are you using?